# Why was this question migrated to SO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, migration

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/51794/revisions) was migrated to SO. I was wondering why, since it's not a particularly good fit for SO:

- Image of (pseudo?) code: a big no-no.
- Asking to read paper by a 3rd party and find an error in it: not related to programming.
- Incomplete: OP isn't even sure about the meaning of the inputs.

To me it seems that, even with the issues it has fixed, the question would fit better here than there, since it requires expertise in signal processing, not in programming.

Comment: i think i agree that the question is most on-topic here rather than SO.

Comment: i think 3 mods read this.

Comment: The good news is that the question got six votes and an accepted answer over there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, to your surprise, the moderator who migrated this question does read the meta DSP.

Answer (score 1):

I did migrate this question and here is my reasoning behind it.

- Is it about the DSP? Yes.
- Is it about programming? Yes
- Which one of the above is it mostly about? My bet is on programming.

I did like this question a lot, and I do realise that similar questions get closed or not being answered on DSP SE. I know that SO has many users with DSP knowledge (including many DSP SE users), so it was only a matter of time before the OP will get his answer.

Comment: If a question is about programming, it needs to have code, not pseudo-code. The question was about what was wrong with the *description of the algorithm* in a paper, not with any code. Yes, the question got an answer over there, and (I'm stumped) 6 upvotes. If it had been tagged with a tag like C++, Java, Python or MATLAB, the question would have been closed in short order, because it contained only a picture of pseudo-code. This is not the type of question typically valued on SO. I'm letting you know for future reference.

Comment: Sorry if this comes across harsh or berating. I mean simply to give feedback. I have all the respect for your work as a moderator. It's a lot of work you're doing for free. Thank you!

Comment: No offence taken. I appreciate that users are active in moderating this site. I am not claiming that I made the right decision, even though it seemed like that back then. Sometimes when you have to step through many reviews & flags it’s easy to make a mistake.